# "narrowing conversion" warning for hex literal with no-suffix?

Tags: c++

```
static int var[2] __attribute__ ((aligned (8))) =
{
    0x0255cfa8,
    0xfdfcddfc
};
```

Why am I getting a warning: `narrowing conversion of '4261207548u' from 'unsigned int' to 'int' inside { } is ill-formed in C++11 [-Wnarrowing]`?

Even though the numbers have no `u` or `U` suffix they seem to be taken as unsigned?

Comment: `0xfdfcddfc` doesn't fit in a (signed) int, so what did you expect it to do?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal#The_type_of_the_literal

Comment: use this code to check ```if((int)j < 0) 
  {
   printf("Negative!\n");
  }``` either the int are signed or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `int` is 32 bit on your platform, then `0xfdfcddfc` is an `unsigned`. That's because you've used hexadecimal notation.

Your helpful compiler is warning you that that number is too big for an `int`.

Note that if you written the denary equivalent, then it would be a `signed` type (`long` or `long long`) and the compiler would have issued a subtly different warning.

Reference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal#The_type_of_the_literal

Comment: How do I know that in hex notation the number is unsigned, and in dec notation it would have been signed? Can this be found in the C++ standard?

Comment: @Danijel: Yup, in the link I provided, note the column headed "binary, octal, or hexadecimal bases". One of those curious corners of the language.

Comment: OK, figured it out after reading that page several times. "The type of the literal is the first type in which the value can fit, from the list of types..." For hex base and with no suffix the list is: int, unsigned int, long int, unsigned long int, etc. The first that fits is taken. Thanks.

Comment: @Danijel: Congratulations! That knowledge is one for the pub quiz.